# how to change the url of the addressbar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a simple chrome extension for my personal use.

This chrome extension simply loads a webpage from my localhost whenever a new tab is opened.

This is the main code of the extension.

```
<html><head>
<script>
function loadUrl() {
  document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0;URL=http://localhost/my">');
  return null;
}
loadUrl();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The problem i'm facing now is that, when i open a tab, the focus is not set to the address bar, apart from that my address bar is filled with obviously `"http://localhost/my"`.

I wanted to clear the address bar and set focus to it.

I have been googling for some time now and always being redirected to this

```
window.history.pushState('string', 'Title', '');
```

which is not so useful for me. I appreciate for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome prohibited access to the address bar in (you can add hash but not clear the content).

The only *solution* is the Omnibox API (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox)

Comment: at the least is there no solution to set focus on the address bar